# Simple ads module drupal 7 ads gone after click

Tags: javascript, html, css, drupal-7

I am using a simple ads module to display a block of advertisements,it displaying advertisements but if i click anywhere in site, advertisements block stops displaying.To display it again i need to edit the content again and active that ad but after activating ad again it creates the same problem.The problem is that i have to go to backend again and again after each click to activate that ad.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same problem as you, what you have to do is to add your ads to a campaign then set
a number of impressions/clicks or days it is up to you, after you do that go and activate each ad from the backend and it will work for you.